# How to play video at rate 2.0 with audio via AVPlayer iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm doing a video player on iOS. I want to have feature to play video at 2.0 playback speed. But when I set rate 2.0, video can play but there is no sound here. Please help me and tell me what I was wrong. Bellow is my code:

```
        let url = URL(string: self.url)

        let asset = AVAsset(url: url!)

        if (!asset.isPlayable) {
            print (self.url + " cannot to play.")
            return

        }

        let playItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        playItem.audioTimePitchAlgorithm = AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithm.lowQualityZeroLatency
        self.player = MyAVPlayer(playerItem: playItem)

        self.playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        self.playerViewController?.player = self.player
        self.player?.allowsExternalPlayback = true

        // self.playerViewController?.showsPlaybackControls = self.showControl

        if (self.autoPlay) {
           // player?.play()
            player?.play()
            player?.rate = 2.0
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after one month research. It's really simple, replace 2.0 to 1.99.
I think there is a problem when swift cast 2.0 to float value, maybe value after cast is 2.00000000003, greater than 2.0 and its not work.